# set selected index in JCombobox as cell editor in a jtable at edit starts

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jcombobox, tablecelleditor

I am a beginner in Java Programming. I want to use a JComboBox as a cell editor in a JTable. But I want to set the selected index of JCombobox on the value which is the current value of the cell when it is clicked to get edited. How I can do this?

the Class which I used for the cell and also for the items of Jcombobox:

```
public class PersianLetterIDPair {              
    private int id;
    private String letter;

    public PersianLetterIDPair(int id, String description)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.letter = description;
    }

    public int getID()
    {
        return id;
    }

    public String getLetter()
    {
        return letter;
    }


    public void setID(int inID)
    {
        id = inID;
    }

    public void setLetter(String inLetter)
    {
        letter = inLetter;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return letter;
    }
```

}

the way I filled my Jcombobox:

```
Vector<PersianLetterIDPair> model2 = new Vector<PersianLetterIDPair>();


                        model1 = myDBLayer
                                .getVectorPersianLettersIDContent();
                        int tPLID;
                        String tPL;

                        Iterator iterator = model1.iterator();
                        while (iterator.hasNext()) {

                            Vector newRow = new Vector();
                            newRow = (Vector) iterator.next();
                            tPLID = (Integer) newRow.get(0);
                            tPL = (String) newRow.get(1);

                            model2.addElement(new PersianLetterIDPair(tPLID,
                                    tPL));
                        }

                        PersianLetters0001 = new JComboBox(model2);
                        jTable2.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setCellEditor(new  DefaultCellEditor(PersianLetters0001));
```

I used a table model for my Jtable as follow:

```
public class FormSimilaritiesTableModel  extends AbstractTableModel {

private DBLayer myDBLayer = new DBLayer();
private ResultSet rs;
private String colNames[];
private Vector<FormSimilarityRow> allRows;
private FormSimilarityRow row;
private Vector<FormSimilarityRow> newRow;

private int li_cols;

private String tableName;
private ResultSetMetaData myM;

private Vector<FormSimilarityRow> deletedKeys;
private Vector newRows;
private Vector updatedRows;

private boolean ibRowInserted = false;
private guiBaseTables myGuiBaseTables ;
boolean ibRowNew = false;

FormSimilaritiesTableModel() {

    deletedKeys = new Vector();
    newRows = new Vector();
    updatedRows = new Vector();
    try {
        ResultSet rs = myDBLayer.getrsFormSimilarities();
        li_cols = 3 ;
        colNames = new String[li_cols];
        colNames[0] = "Persian Letter 1";
        colNames[1] = "Persian Letter 2";
        colNames[2] = "Form Similarity";            
        allRows = new Vector<FormSimilarityRow>();
        int rPLID1;
        String rPL1;
        int rPLID2;
        String rPL2;
        while (rs.next()) {
            ///newRow = new Vector();
            rPLID1 = (Integer) rs.getObject(1);
            rPL1 = (String) rs.getObject(2);

            rPLID2 = (Integer) rs.getObject(3);
            rPL2 = (String) rs.getObject(4);


            allRows.addElement(new FormSimilarityRow(new PersianLetterIDPair(rPLID1, rPL1),new PersianLetterIDPair(rPLID2, rPL2), (Integer)rs.getObject(5)));

        } // while

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }

}

public Class getColumnClass(int col) {


        if (col == 0 || col == 1) {
            return PersianLetterIDPair.class;
        } else if (col == 2) {
            return Integer.class;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
}

public String getColumnName(int col) {      
    return colNames[col];
}

public int getColumnCount() {
    return li_cols;
}

public int getRowCount() {
    return allRows.size();
}

public Object getValueAt(int arow, int col) {
    row =  allRows.elementAt(arow);
    if(col == 0){           
        PersianLetterIDPair pL1 = row.getPL1();
        return pL1.getLetter();
    }
    else
    if(col == 1){           
        PersianLetterIDPair pL2 = row.getPL2();
        return pL2.getLetter();
    }
    else{
        return row.getFS();
    }

}

public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) {
    int totalNewRows;                   
    if (col == 0 || col == 1) {
        totalNewRows = newRows.size();
        for(int j = 0; j< totalNewRows; j++)
        {
            int rVal = ((Integer) newRows.get(j)).intValue();               
            if(  rVal == row + 1){
                return true;
            }                               
        }
        return false;


    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int aRow, int aCol) {     

    FormSimilarityRow dataRow =  allRows.elementAt(aRow);
    if (aCol == 0){     
        PersianLetterIDPair sV = (PersianLetterIDPair) aValue;
        dataRow.setPL1(sV);
    }
    else 
    if (aCol == 1){     
        PersianLetterIDPair sV = (PersianLetterIDPair) aValue;
        dataRow.setPL2(sV);

    }
    else        
        dataRow.setFS((Integer) aValue);
    fireTableCellUpdated(aRow, aCol);
}
...
```

}

and definition of my Jtable is as:

```
myFormSimilaritiesTableModel = new FormSimilaritiesTableModel();
                        jTable2 = new JTable();
                        jScrollPane2.setViewportView(jTable2);
                        jTable2.setModel(myFormSimilaritiesTableModel);
                        jTable2.setSelectionMode(javax.swing.ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
                        jTable2.getTableHeader()
                                .setReorderingAllowed(false);
```

I changed the getValueAt method following the tip which was said by @Polet to return the PersianLetterIDPair:

```
public Object getValueAt(int arow, int col) {
    row =  allRows.elementAt(arow);
    if(col == 0){           
        PersianLetterIDPair pL1 = row.getPL1();
        //return pL1.getLetter();
        return pL1;
    }
    else
    if(col == 1){           
        PersianLetterIDPair pL2 = row.getPL2();
        //return pL2.getLetter();
        return pL2;
    }
    else{
        return row.getFS();
    }

}
```

Then I create a TableCellRenderer:

```
class PersianLetterIDPairRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer
```

{

```
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
        super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);       
        setText(((PersianLetterIDPair)value).getLetter());              
        return this;
    }
```

}

Then I add to my Jtable:

```
TableColumn tCol = jTable2.getColumnModel().getColumn(0);
                        tCol.setCellRenderer(new PersianLetterIDPairRenderer());
                        tCol = jTable2.getColumnModel().getColumn(1);
                        tCol.setCellRenderer(new PersianLetterIDPairRenderer());
```

But it gets correct when I disconnected from the TableCellRenderer as:

```
TableColumn tCol = jTable2.getColumnModel().getColumn(0);
                        //tCol.setCellRenderer(new PersianLetterIDPairRenderer());
                        tCol = jTable2.getColumnModel().getColumn(1);
                        //tCol.setCellRenderer(new PersianLetterIDPairRenderer());
```

Comment: You could initialise the value in the getTableCellEditorComponent method

Comment: Use a [DefaultCellEditor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultCellEditor.html#DefaultCellEditor%28javax.swing.JComboBox%29), which does that for you.

Comment: this value came from XxxTableModel,

Comment: You should also override `equals` so that it returns true when id and letters are themselves `equals`. something like `public boolean equals(Object o){if (o instanceof PersianLetterIDPair){PersianLetterIDPair p = (PersianLetterIDPair)o; return p.id == id && p.letter.equals(letter);}return false;}`

Answer (score 1):

Check out This link [Click here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#combobox)

OR

See this little example :

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumn;

public class TableTest extends JFrame {

    JTable table ;
    public TableTest(){
        table = new JTable(4,2);
        String []subject = {"Java Programming","Hoshang","Mathematics","Database"};
        String []lecturer={"Nuhara","Jon","Saran","Mikey"};
        table.setSize(200, 200);
        JComboBox subj = new JComboBox(subject);
        JComboBox lec = new JComboBox(lecturer);

        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(lec));
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(subj));
        /*
         * OR you can use TableColumn 
         *  
         */
//        TableColumn tc = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0);
//        tc.setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(subj));


        this.add(new JScrollPane(table),BorderLayout.CENTER);
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setSize(300,200);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(3);
    }
    public static void main(String...ag){
        new TableTest();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide a real answer, that will be readable ad vitam aeternam, rather than just a link.

Comment: @JBNizet  Thanks, I edited The answer and posted an example .

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I did the same but it doesn't work in my program. I should mention that there is a difference in my code. My JComboBox model is not an array of string, because I wanted to have a hidden value for each item in the JComboBox, I created a class which keeps and id and des and then I fill my Jcombobox with objects of this class. In the other side, the class of my cell is the same as mentioned class in my tablemodel. But each time a jcombobox opens as a cell editor , its selected index is not the same as current value of clicked cell.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested, use the `DefaultCellEditor` with a `JComboBox`.

Small working example demonstrating this:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Vector;

import javax.swing.DefaultCellEditor;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class TestTable2 {

    protected void initUI() {
        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            model.addColumn("Col-" + (i + 1));
        }
        Random random = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < 2000; i++) {
            Vector<Object> row = new Vector<Object>();
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                row.add(VALUES[random.nextInt(VALUES.length)]);
            }
            model.addRow(row);
        }
        JTable table = new JTable(model);
        DefaultCellEditor editor = new DefaultCellEditor(new JComboBox(VALUES));
        for (int i = 0; i < table.getColumnCount(); i++) {
            table.getColumnModel().getColumn(i).setCellEditor(editor);
        }
        JFrame frame = new JFrame(TestTable2.class.getSimpleName());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JScrollPane scrollpane = new JScrollPane(table);
        frame.add(scrollpane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException,
            UnsupportedLookAndFeelException {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new TestTable2().initUI();
            }
        });
    }

    private static final String[] VALUES = { "Sun", "Hello", "Sky", "Cloud", "World", "Time", "System", "Computer", "Dummy", "Simple",
            "Today", "Lorem" };

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I did the same but it doesn't work in my program. I should mention that there is a difference in my code. My JComboBox model is not an array of string, because I wanted to have a hidden value for each item in the JComboBox, I created a class which keeps and id and des and then I fill my Jcombobox with objects of this class. In the other side, the class of my cell is the same as mentioned class in my tablemodel. But each time a jcombobox opens as a cell editor , its selected index is not the same as current value of clicked cell.

Comment: @Leila that's perfectly fine the way you did it. The only thing to ensure is that the `equals` method will return true when 2 items are the same. You probably have to override `equals` in your dedicated class if you have different instances of the same object so that it returns `true` when appropriate.

Comment: what happens exactly when equals method is called? I added it but there is no difference in the behavior of the JComboBox, when it opens in a cell as a celleditor, its selected index is on the one which have been selected in the  previous Jcombobox which opened and closed before this one maybe in the other similar cells. Could I tell you exactly what happens?

Comment: Describing more: A JCombobox opens in a cell and the user select one item of it like 'A'. Then The user clicks on the other type-similar cell to edit that one, the value of the selected cell is for example 'C'. But when the JComboBox opens in this cell, its selected value is 'A' which was selected in the previous just closed jcombobox, not 'C' which it should be. Is my description clear? If not, let me know . Thanks. I added the equals method as you told but it doesn't get different.

Comment: @Leila Then it means that the content of the first column of your table are not objects of the type `PersianLetterIDPair`. It would be helpful if you provided the code for the JTable too. Simplest thing would be to provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org). It would avoid all these lengthy comments.

Comment: I don't know how to provide a SSCCE, so I added the definition of Jtable and its table model to my question. Thanks a lot for your consideration. :)

Comment: The content of the columns which I use this JComboBox as their cell editor is from PersianLetterIDPair

Comment: @Leila the problem is that the content of column 0 and 1 are not `PersianLetterIDPair` but `String`. You return the letter of the `PersianLetterIDPair`. Instead, return the `PersianLetterIDPair` directly and set a `TableCellRenderer` for `PersianLetterIDPair` which extends `DefaultTableCellRenderer`, override `getTableCellRendererComponent`, call `super.getTableCellRendererComponent()` and then call `setText(((PersianLetterIDPair)value).getLetter());`

Comment: Following your guidance, I changed the getValueAt method in my Jtable and set a TableCellRenderer and assigned it to the column of 0 and 1. I added the changes above to below the question. But dear Polet There was no difference till I removed the cellRenderer, then It gets correct. It means just by returning PersianLetterIDPair. Do you have any Idea? Did I added the cell renderer corectly? Anyway It works now.